# Discrete Mathematics what exactly does from A to B mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Like if there's some relation $R$ from a set $A$ to a set $B$ what exactly does this mean?

I know it's just a subset of the Cartesian product $A\times B,$ but what exactly does from $A$ to $B$ mean..? Like obviously from $B$ to $A$ is different so can anyone explain what the FROM really means here?

Comment: From $A$ to $B$ means $A\times B$ and vice versa.

Comment: The typical class of relations mathematicians deal with are functions, like $f(x)=x^2.$. This is represented as the set of pairs $(x,x^2).$. Here, the "from" is the domain of the function. In general relations, of course, symmetric, in that the set of $R^{op}=\{(y,x)\mid (x,y)\in R\}$ is also a relationship, so there isn't really much difference between the "from" set and the "to" set. But if $R$ represents a function, then $R^{op}$ does not, in general.

Comment: So, "from $A$ to $B$" is really just a convention, in the set theory notion of a relation. We choose this order as primary because we are, in the end, mostly interested in functions. But again, that is just a convention, too

Answer (score 1):

Elements of the set $A\times B$ are tuples $(a, b)$, while elements of $B\times A$ are tuples $(b,a)$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

So, a relation $R\subseteq A\times B$ is different from a relation $R'\subseteq B\times A$, because their elements differ in the order of the tuples' components. Hence, order matters.

As a last note: In my environment, I've heard the phrase "from A to B" when it regards a function (not just any relation) with domain A and codomain B.